# How do I save a program using Python Idle?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a Mac Ver 10.6.8 and have just installed Python 3.3 with IDLE.  I am brand new and this is my first program language I am learning, no prior experience. I am using Wikibooks guide for new programmers.  I have done the "Hello World" but after it talks about saving it using 
-> File -> save as.  I feel stupid but I do not see this feature or area where i can select file.  I have a screenshot but cannot not post because I do not have the rep points.

Comment: On a Mac the `File` menu is at the top of your screen...

Answer (score 0):

1. File
2. Save As
3. name it
4. Save

your file will be saved with .py extension, which is a Python script file.